# Drupal form redirect to fragment

Tags: php, forms, drupal, redirect, drupal-6

I have a poll block in the bottom of my front page, and I'd like to redirect the poll form to the block after submit. I use Drupal 6.x.
As usual, I use `form_alter` for this.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'poll_view_voting':
      // not worked also
      //$form['#redirect'] = url('', array('fragment' => 'poll-block'));
      $form['#redirect'] = '#poll-block';
      break;
  }
}
```

After submit, I'm redirected to `/%2523poll_block` (this is a 404 page).

In a `preprocess_page` function I wrote the `$_REQUEST['q']` using `drupal_set_message()`, and it shows the good redirect (#poll-block), but the URL in browser is encoded.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [FAPI reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6), you can enter an array to be passed to [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6). Ultimately this goes through [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/6) so use your url() function's ninja tricks here.

Basically you can have 3 types of data here. 
a string, Boolean FALSE, or an array. 
If it's a string, it will redirect to the correct location after a url encode (what happens in your case). FALSE will disable redirects, and if you enter an array, it will be passed to drupal_goto().

So for your case, it would be:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'poll_view_voting':
      // not worked also
      //$form['#redirect'] = url('', array('fragment' => 'poll-block'));
      //$form['#redirect'] = array('node/54', array('page' => '2'), 'poll-block'); // No "#" in fragment. This will work.
       $form['#redirect'] = array('', array(), 'poll-block');
      break;
  }
}
```

However, drupal_goto() usually happens with absolute URL so probably your effort would be useless unless you use javascript.